# Is There A Way i Can Make A Auto-Warn And Auto-Kick Thing

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Error: No, because i haven't made the code/ i don't know how to make the code, the code is below

```
 @bot.event
 async def on_message(message):
     test = 'test'
     if test in message.content.lower():
          await message.author.send('you have been warned for using "bad words" in the server')
```

I want my code to warn the user 3 times then in the 4th time the bot kicks the user for writing test in the the server, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol How?? Also make sure i am using **Discord.py-rewrite**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a map of user ids to the number of times they have been warned.  The easiest way to persist this map while the bot is offline is to store it in a JSON file, though as your bot scales you should eventually adopt a database.

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from json import load

bot = Bot("!")

try:
    with open("warns.json") as f:
        warns = load(f)
except:
    warns = {}

def should_warn(message):
    return 'test' in message.content.lower()

async def warn_or_kick(member):
    id = str(member.id)
    if id not in warns:
        warns[id] = 0
    warns[id] += 1
    if warns[id] >= 4:
        await member.send("You have been kicked")
        await member.kick()
    else:
        await member.send(f"This is warning number {warn[id]}")
    with open("warns.json") as f:
        dump(warns, f)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user == message.author:
        return 
    if should_warn(message):
        await warn_or_kick(message.author)
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Comment: Presumably you can't save files long term then.  In that case I would recommend using their database service, I'm afraid I don't know how it works however.